# C# Java Named pipe stability

Tags: c#, java, named-pipes

I am having stability issues using a named pipe for communication between a C# and Java app.

Here is the code that sets up the named pipe in C# and reads lines of XML strings.

```
try
{
    NamedPipeServerStream inStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(inName, PipeDirection.In);
    inStream.WaitForConnection();
    reader = new StreamReader(inStream);
    while (!Stopped && !reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string xml = reader.ReadLine();
        processXml(xml);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.Error("Error in receiver", e);
}
finally
{
    log.Info("Receiver ended");
}
```

And here is the connection and write code in Java

```
public void connect() throws TransportUnavailableException
{
    try
    {
        File inPipe = new File(inName);
        os = new FileOutputStream(inPipe);
        // Uses JAXB for XML serialization
        marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        throw new TransportUnavailableException("Named pipe not found: " + inName);
    }
}

public void send(Message message)
{
    marshaller.marshal(message, os);
    os.write('\n');
    os.flush();
}
```

Everything works fine normally. But many users are reporting crashes. I don't see any exceptions in logs that suggest a reason for the pipe dying. I just see that the receiving thread in C# ends (i.e. 'Receiver ended' in the logs) and after this I get an IO exception on the next attempted send from Java with a message 'The handle is invalid'. This seems to happen randomly, but usually within the 1st minute or 2 after the connection was established. The pipe ending message also happens when the application is not doing anything, it could have been minutes since the last user operation. Then it could be a few more minutes before the next write is attempted from Java.

All reasons for my app to bring down the pipe on purpose (e.g. a crash elsewhere in system) are logged and I never see that as a reason for the pipe ended, I just get the message that the reader has given up reading.

- Could there be any external reason for the pipe being killed, anti-virus, firewall etc?
- I noticed I didn't use a RandomAccessFile from Java like most examples seem to use. Could this be a reason?

Any help/suggestion appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting up a test environment, isolating the named-pipe-stuff? I could imagine some timeout is hitting here.

Comment: Are the two processes on the same machine?

Comment: @antlersoft Yes both processes are on the same machine

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I can't highlight the problem on a development machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server side code only processes one connection, then it exits when it reads to EOS. You need to create the named pipe, loop accepting connections, and spin up a new thread to handle each connection. You also need to close each connection when you're finished with it.

However I would use TCP rather than named pipes for this, for several reasons.

Comment: There is only 1 connection and it should live for the lifetime of the C# application. There are obviously multiple (1000's) of messages per session. What would be the reasons for moving to TCP/sockets?

Comment: Stability? And you have the option to move the two to seperate machines. And on the local stack, I can imagine it to even perform better. If TCP/IP is not an option, I'd at least implement EJP's improvements.

Comment: @Fildor TCP/IP is an option. But I need to justify why it would be more stable. The application is live now and my employer definitely won't like a 'lets just try this approach'

Comment: And why would I need to loop accepting multiple client connections when I only ever expect 1?

Comment: In that case, I'd go for EJPs answer except for the TCP/IP part. You need to loop, because connections can time out and they can be tried to be reestablished. Even if you expect 1 to exist ever, for stability, you'll support more.

Comment: Maybe you misread my comment, TCP/IP is an option. Just wondering why you would do everything except that?

Comment: If you have difficulties promoting TCP, just do the other stuff first. If that works - fine. Then you do not need a big change to TCP/IP.